# code comes out to be errored

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a code, which has showed up correctly but sometimes when a client orders, it will give me a mysql error code as below.

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 39

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 40

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 42

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 43

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 44

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 45

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 46
```

once these codes are in place they remove the name, address, phone number etc the member info from viewing the order. i have tried all possible options but i am not sure whats wrong with my code any help would be appreciated.

my code is below:

this coding is from the lines giving by the error.

```
$queryt = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MID = '$CUSTOMER' ";
$resultt = mysql_query($queryt) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$numt=mysql_numrows($resultt);

$FIRSTNAME=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"FIRSTNAME");
$LASTNAME=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"LASTNAME");
$EMAIL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"EMAIL");
$PHONE=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PHONE");
$ADDRESS1=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ADDRESS1");
$ADDRESS2=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ADDRESS2");
$CITY=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CITY");
$STATE=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"STATE");



?>
<? echo $FIRSTNAME?><br />
<? echo $LASTNAME?><br />
<? echo $EMAIL?><br />
<? echo $PHONE?><br />
<? echo $ADDRESS1?><br />
<? echo $ADDRESS2?><br />
<? echo $CITY?><br />
<? echo $STATE?><br />
<br />
<br />
```

also the error doesnt happen with everyone, alot of members can order fine without any error issue, but some have the issue at random moments so its not the same person.

Comment: You are using `$it` - but should refer to `$numt`. However, **0** would be adequate.

Comment: $it is the problem, BUT mysql_* functions are your real problem...they're all depreciated.  You should be using mysqli_*

Comment: il give that a try and see my result, i get all results for the name and orders etc just on a various moment i get an error.

Comment: when i put $numt it errors out entire order.

Comment: putting 0 there instead of $it still produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did your query return any results?

```
$numt=mysql_numrows($resultt);

if ($numt > 0) {
    echo "rows found";
} else {
    echo "none found";
}
```

It looks like you are trying to find values in an empty result set. You need to verify that you actually got a result back before attempting to work with the result data.

Comment: yes it works, it retrieves the information submitted to the database just happens on ocasion

Comment: The error you see indicates that MySQL can't extract record/row 0 (which means either that data is corrupt, or it doesn't exist) Add the test for the count of the results and print out a message if the result count is `zero`.  I'm fairly confident that you are getting no results. Even if you aren't, you should code defensively for the potential that there are no results.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the many, many problems with the code, this probably happens because you skip the case when the query is executed successfully, but returns 0 rows. Add that check, and you should be fine.

Here are some potential other problems with the code:

- potentially vulnerable to SQL injection due to not escaping data
- using the deprecated `mysql_*` functionality (use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`)
- depends on `short_tags` directive to be on
- inconsistent variable naming standards
- `mysql_query(/**/) or die();` - can show error messages to users (security vulnerability)

Comment: well my result comes out fine, minus on some occasions where i get the mysql error. its not the same clients that get it orelse i would say that would be the issue, but its on various clients.